# jQuery component in directive with ng-include

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I am using a jQuery component in angular with a directive like this:

```
angular.module('directives.flavr', [])

    .directive('flavr', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function () {
                    new $.flavr({
                        title: 'Form',
                        content: 'HTML form example',
                        dialog: 'form',
                        form: {content: '<div ng-include="directives/flavr/templates/loginForm.tpl.html"></div>', method: 'post'},
                        onSubmit: function ($container, $form) {
                            alert($form.serialize());
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

The `flavr` popup accept an HTML to build the modal window, is it possible to use a $templateCache html file to store this html ?

If it isn't possible, what is the best way to "pass" som random HTML content to my directive to render whatever I like ?

Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
<flavr html="/* I want to put a templatecache url and be able to load it when the popup is open */"></flavr>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: may be` ng-transclude `will help you in this case

Comment: can use templateCache or script tag template for `templateUrl` in directive. If neither is found then it will make ajax request to same path on server

Comment: I dont think that using jquery component to show angular html is good idea. If u want just to display static html text, then just load it from teplateCache manyally $templateCache.get(attrs.html)